# Maven 2.2.1 on Windows 7 64-bit

Tags: maven-2, 32bit-64bit, java, windows-7-x64

For various reasons, I must stick with older versions of Java (6) and Maven (2.2). So with that I mind, I installed [Maven 2.2.1](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/maven/maven-2/2.2.1/binaries/apache-maven-2.2.1-bin.zip) while my system uses the **64-bit** JDK 6.

I tried to verify that it is correctly installed by running `mvn --version` and what I received in response was:

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory.
JAVA_HOME = "C:\Windows:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_37"
Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation
```

I am suspecting that Maven expects the **32-bit** version of Java and that it cannot deal with 64-bit Java. Is this true?

If indeed this is the case, setting the `%JAVA_HOME%` environment variable to point the 32-bit version (already installed) is **not** what I would like to do because it will then fail other tools installed on my PC that count on it pointing to the 64-bit version.

Is there a way around this?

**UPDATE:** Problem solved by inserting into `maven.bat` the following line (just before `=== START VALIDATION ===`):

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_37
```

This way, this `%JAVA_HOME%` environment change is localized to Maven and is not visible outside.

If there is a better solution, I would be happy to know about it.

Comment: Where is the relationship to Maven 2.2.1 and the Java version ? You should use Maven 3.0.X instead of Maven 2.2.1 ...

Comment: @khmarbaise I am using the [xmlbeans-maven-plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13707097/1864054) which only supports Maven 2, not 3. So unfortunately I can't use Maven 3.

Comment: Where is that written? I don't see a hint on the mojo codehaus pages that this plugin works only in Maven 2...?

Comment: @khmarbaise http://mojo.codehaus.org/xmlbeans-maven-plugin/index.html

Comment: The point is that Maven 3 is a drop-in replacement for Maven 2. So usually there are no problems with Maven plugins. This was mentioned there, cause to make clear it can't be used with Maven 1.

Comment: @khmarbaise OK, that's good to know that at some point I will be able to upgrade to Maven 3 without losing the `xmlbeans-maven-plugin`. I am working within a team that dictates that we should still stay with Maven 2, so the constraint is still there, but as seen in my answer below, I solved my problem: Maven really needs a valid `%JAVA_HOME%`. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The source of the problem was in front of my eyes all that time but I didn't see it:

The %JAVA_HOME% env var was set to `%SystemRoot%\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_37` instead of `%SystemDrive%\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_37`.

Once fixed, no modification of `maven.bat` is required.