# xmlbeans-maven-plugin not finding javac

Tags: maven, javac, m2e, xmlbeans, xmlbeans-maven-plugin

I am trying to setup [xmlbeans-maven-plugin 2.3.3](http://mojo.codehaus.org/xmlbeans-maven-plugin/dependencies.html) in my Eclipse and while everything seems to go OK, It fails with an java.io.IOException due to inability to find the file `C:\Users\Daniel\Workspace\MyProject\javac`.

This is strange because javac [*is*](http://wiki.apache.org/xmlbeans/XmlBeansFaq#scompFindingJavac) on the system's %PATH% so why would it try to find it in %PROJECT_LOC%?

I found [this problem description](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MXMLBEANS-65) which sounds very similar to mine, but I placed the JDK path in front of all other paths and that didn't help.

Any idea **how** to tell the `xmlbeans-maven-plugin` **where** to look for `javac`?

**UPDATE 1:** I tried working around this problem by simply copying `javac.exe` to the project's directory and at least it now finds it but the problem moved forward to:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.tools.javac.Main
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
Exception in thread "main" Could not find the main class: com.sun.tools.javac.Main.  Program will exit.
```

Any insight that could help come up with the *correct* solution to this (e.g. something in [.m2/settings.xml](http://maven.apache.org/settings.html)?) would be appreciated.

**UPDATE 2:** I also tried [this little solution](http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/maven-users/201108.mbox/%3CCAA8BW8F28HgpGctSQ_zG5DkKL-xQQmYYm4CS6ZAE=3A9aoN_9g@mail.gmail.com%3E) I found in my searches:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  <localRepository>c:\maven\repository</localRepository>
   <configuration>
    <compiler>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\javac.exe</compiler>
   </configuration>
</settings>
```

But that didn't help the plugin find `javac`. It still complains about "The system cannot find the file specified" for javac.exe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution! In the **project's** pom.xml, simply add the following inside `<configuration>`:

```
<compiler>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\javac.exe</compiler>
```

i.e.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <configuration>
                <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                <compiler>C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_37\bin\javac.exe</compiler>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Also, be sure to point the `Window -> Preferences -> Java -> installed JREs` to the JDK's, not JRE's: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_37`. As described [in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6810275/1864054).